# How to configure two Codeigniter applications in two directories in Nginx, FastCGI

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have a specific requirement to setup two CodeIgniter based application in same Nginx server pointing to `domain.com/` and `domain.com/site2`.

So far I have tried various combinations of configuration without any luck. Most of the time it gives me 404 error.

Following is my latest configuration file.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
        root   /var/www/domain.com/;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/domain.com/site1/public/;
            index index.html index.php
            access_log /var/www/domain.com/site1/logs/access.log;
            error_log /var/www/domain.com/site1/logs/errors.log;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/main/public$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            }
        }

        location /site2{
            root /var/www/domain.com/site2/public/;
            index index.html index.php;
            access_log /var/www/domain.com/site2/logs/access.log;
            error_log /var/www/domain.com/site2/logs/errors.log;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME
                $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used `alias` in place of `root`  without the domain part. Still no luck.

However when I use `alias` and `try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/site2/public/index.php?$query_string` inside location block, it loads the website without assets like css/js.

Could you please show me what is wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `alias` with `fastcgi` requires you to use [`$request_filename`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename) to compute the correct value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

The `location` value and the `alias` value should either both end with `/` or neither end with `/` to achieve the correct substitution.

```
location /site2 {
    alias /var/www/domain.com/site2/public;
    index index.html index.php;
    access_log /var/www/domain.com/site2/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/site2/logs/errors.log;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /site2/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Use the first `if` block to simulate the `try_files` statement in your question. Avoid using `alias` and `try_file` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Use the second `if` block to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Only one problem though. Site2 is working fine. But site one loads main page only. Inner pages gives nginx 404 error. You have any idea why that happen @RichardSmith

Comment: By *inner pages* are you referring to routes that should be handled by the `/index.php` script? Including `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` into the `location /` block of site1 should do it.

Comment: I used `root` in place of `alias` and added `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string`. CSS and JS  in v2/public/assets were loading though. So I added a symlink `assets' inside 'v2` pointing to `public/assets`, It s all done now. Thank you for your help.